# Phone Gap and Web Services

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to use PhoneGap to package the front-end of my application. This application makes REST calls to the back-end from javascript.

I'm using PhoneGap Build for the build process. I have white-listed all domains in my config.xml file like so: `<access origin="*" />`.

When testing the app on a mobile device (Android), all the html/javascript/css works except for the REST calls. Nothing happens on my back-end server, which is deployed on Tomcat on my machine, and the call appears to timeout on the app.

When the whole application, front- and back-end, is deployed locally everything works as expected.

Here is the **javascript** web service call:

```
$scope.login = function() {
        $log.log($scope.credentials);
        $http.post(navHelp.getContext() + "/login", $scope.credentials).success(
                function(data,status,headers,config) {
                    $log.log( data );                       
                    if(data.loginSuccess === true){                         
                    $location.path('/home');
                    userService.setId(data.employeeId);
                    userService.setAccessToken(data.accessToken);
                    userService.setLoggedIn(true);
                    }

                }).error(function(data){
                    $log.log("Error: " +data);      
                    $scope.error = true;
                });
    };
```

Here is the **Java** web service exposed with the Spark framework:

```
Bootstrap.getExService().execute(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            post(API_CONTEXT + "/login", "application/json", 
                    (request,response) -> {

                     //stuff happening

                    }, new JsonTransformer());
        }
    });
```

I have unblocked tomcat's port in my firewall.
I have added a CORS filter in my web.xml.
I have changed the urls in the webservice requests to point to the server.

What am I missing? Suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.

The solution was two-fold.

**First:**
I needed (?) to use a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to provide a tunnel to my localhost, where the tomcat server was running. The web service calls needed to be directed to the provided ngrock url, which then routed the request to my web server.
I feel like there must be a way around this, but I'm not sure what it is.

**Second:**
Although my CORS filter was already setup, I needed to configure a bit further to accept requests with the origin "file://". To do this, I added the following tags to my web.xml file:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

This allows requests with any origin (which is specified in the request header) to pass through the CORS filter.

Now I can use my app (almost) as effectively on a mobile device as in my browser.

I hope this information can help others who might be having as frustrating an experience as I had.